# How to draw vertical text in canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am trying to draw a taxt in canvas in android , like above picture :
[image: Vertical Text]

I did not found any method for this.
is it possible . thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, `text` is drawn horizontally since the angle of `canvas`'s matrix is 0 degree. To draw text vertically, you need to rotate the canvas 90 or -90 degree and then draw the text. You should do something like the below:

```
canvas.rotate(90, x, y);
canvas.drawText(text, pointX, pointY, paint);
```

More on `rotate` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float,%20float,%20float)).